# SAS: pivot multiple columns to long format

Tags: sas

I have a dataset relating to pregnancy outcomes, where the outcomes for each baby is in wide format.

So, I have the columns:

```
Patient_ID *for the mother;
pofid_1
pof1pregenddate
pof1pregendweeks
pofid_2
pof2pregenddate
pof2pregendweeks
```

etc, etc.

`pofid_1` refers to a unique identifier for each baby, and is the only variable that doesnt follow the format of `pofnvarname` (pof - pregnancy outcome form). There are ~50 columns for each baby, I have only listed three here for demonstration. Is there a way I can pivot the whole dataset based on the number after `pof` so I have the following column names, and one row for each baby born:

```
Patient_ID
babynumber
pofid *baby ID;
pofpregenddate
pofpregendweeks
```

Comment: What do you mean by about 50 variables? Is that 50 times 3? Or more like 17*3=51 variables?  Or are there more than three values collected for each baby?

Comment: ~50 fields per baby - maximum was triplets so ~150 variables in total

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a pivot of sets of grouped variables by using DATA Step arrays.  The naming convention you are dealing with is unfortunately not very useful.  Some pre-processing can be done to create a rename statement that moves the index # to the end of the variable name and then the array processing becomes very straightforward.

Example:

This example hard codes the grouped variables in array statements of the final step.  *Programmatic detection of variables that should be grouped (by common # in their name) is possible but more complicated.*

```
data have(keep=id child:);
  do id = 1 to 10;
    z+1; childid1 = z;
    z+1; child1metricX = z;
    z+1; child1metricY = z;

    z+1; childid2 = z;
    z+1; child2metricX = z;
    z+1; child2metricY = z;

    z+1; childid3 = z;
    z+1; child3metricX = z;
    z+1; child3metricY = z;

    output;
  end;
run;

proc contents noprint data=have out=havevars;
run;

proc sql;
  create table newnames as
  select name, prxchange('s/child(\d+)([^ ]+)\s*/child$2_$1/i',-1,name) as newname
  from havevars
  where upcase(name) like 'CHILD%'
  ;

proc sql noprint;
  * create rename option;
  select 
    catx('=',name,newname)
  , newname
  into
    :renames separated by ' '
  , :drops separated by ' '
  from newnames
  ;
quit;

data want;
  set have (rename=(&renames));

  array childids childid:;
  array metricXs childmetricX:;
  array metricYs childmetricY:;

  do over childids;
    childnum = _i_;      * do over tacitly creates _i_;
    childid = childids;  * automatic implicit array index is _i_;
    metricX = metricXs;
    metrucY = metricYs;
    output;
  end;

  drop &drops;
run;
```

Have:

[image]

Want (result):

[image]

Comment: I like this solution because it retains the formatting of the columns - but is there a way to deal with this without having to specify an array for each variable name? This works for two metics (x and y), but not when there are ~50

Comment: A lot of that would be based on the variable naming patterns, i.e. where is the digit(s) part.  Regardless of approach you need a robust consistent computation for calculating the group (i.e childnum) and simplified name (i.e. the transposed column name).  After that is done, the data want step can be abstracted with macro code.  Create a new question if you want to extend the scope of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to transpose ALL of them first.  Then you could parse out the baby number from the name of the variable.

```
proc transpose data=have out=tall ;
  by patientid;
  var pof: ;
run;
data tall2;
  set tall ;
  _name_=upcase(_name_);
  if _name_=:'POFID_' then do;
    babynumber=input(scan(_name_,2,'_'),32.);
    _name_='POFID';
  end;
  else do;
    _name_=substr(_name_,4);
    loc=verify(_name_,'0123456789');
    babynumber=input(substr(_name_,1,loc-1),32.);
     _name_=substr(_name_,loc);
  end;
  drop loc;
run;
```

If you want you could just leave it in this TALL format. Or you could sort and transpose it back into the semi-wide format.

```
 proc sort data=tall2;
   by patientid babynumber;
 run;
 proc transpose data=tall2 out=want;
   by patientid babynumber;
   id _name_;
   var col1;
 run;
```